# does jqGrid support paging using keybind?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with inline-editing, virtual-scrolling, and key-binding enabled. I do **not** have multi-select enabled (which is what my searches thus far have yielded results for).

When I press the down arrow, the next row in the grid is selected. When my selected value reaches the bottom of the visible area, the grid scrolls to accommodate the newly selected row.

When I reach row 40 (my rowNum), the down key does nothing. I half way expected it to load the next 40 rows, but I suppose I should have known better.

My question is, "How can I use the down-arrow's keypress to load the next 40 records and append them to the grid?"

Using the mouse scroll wheel, or dragging the scrollbar works fine. However, my users would insta-rage if I told them they have to scroll with the mouse to load additional data.

> "Why can't you just plug the mouse wheel code *into* the down arrow code?
>
> Why is this taking so long!?
>
> Why can't you just make this work."
>
> Etc, etc.

I am aware of the following methods:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{page:2});
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

However, I'm not sure how to plug them into the keydown / onSelectRow event. Additionally, I have concerns about scrolling back up after data gets trimmed.

Here's some grid code:

```
grid.jqGrid({
    scroll: 1,
    url: dataUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    rowNum: 40,
    editurl: editUrl,
    colNames: dataHelper.columnNames(),
    colModel: dataHelper.columnModels(),
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 30,
    altrows: true,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: pagerId,
    sortname: "id",
    sortorder: "desc",
    gridview: true,
    jsonReader:{repeatitems: false},
    ondblClickRow: function(){
        var row_id = grid.getGridParam('selrow');
        $(grid).editRow(row_id, true);
    },
    onSelectRow: function(rowid, status, e){
        var reccount = grid.getGridParam("reccount");
        var page = grid.getGridParam("page");

        if(****SOME CONDITION****){
            grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{page: page+1});
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    }
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', pagerId,{edit:false,add:false,del:false, searchtext: "Search", refreshtext: "Refresh"});
grid.jqGrid("inlineNav", pagerId, {edittext: "Edit", addtext: "Add", savetext: "Save", canceltext: "Cancel", deletetext: "Delete", addParams: {position: "afterSelected"}});
grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true});
grid.jqGrid("bindKeys", {scrollingRows: true, onEnter: function(rowid){grid.editRow(rowid, true);}});
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: nope. sorry. its just a known 'bug' in my system at the moment. jqgrid's developers have been pretty vocal in suggesting people don't actually use the virtual scrolling feature.